# Generate a variable for a role in an ansible play

Tags: variables, ansible

My objective is to dynamically generate a list of dictionaries and use it for a role I need.

I've managed to generate the variable, but now I cannot pass it to the role.

This is my play:

```
- hosts:
   - some-hosts
  tasks:
    - name: create zkh var
      vars:
        zkh: []
      set_fact:
        zkh: "{{ zkh + [ {'host': item.1, 'id': item.0} ] }}"
      with_indexed_items: "{{ groups.some-hosts }}"
  roles:
    - {role: ansible-zookeeper, zookeeper_hosts: "{{ zkh }}" }
```

In the task I generate my variable, but then I cannot pass it to the role as (I imagine), I cannot access the scope where it is defined (`"AnsibleUndefinedVariable: ERROR! ERROR! 'zkh' is undefined"}`).

Defining a play-level variable and having a new task to assign it with `set_fact` and the value of `zkh` doesn't help.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Try using `pre_tasks` instead of `tasks` to create the variable, then you should be able to access the var

Comment: Thanks @shaps, this worked!

Comment: @shaps, please write that as an answer so I can accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `pre_tasks` to define variables needed in a role. `pre_tasks` are just a list of tasks that are executed before applying a role.

You also have `post_tasks`, if you need to do something after applying roles.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this playbook structure:

```
- hosts: 
    - some-hosts
  tasks:
    - name: create zkh var
      vars:
        zkh: []
      set_fact:
        zkh: "{{ zkh + [ {'host': item.1, 'id': item.0} ] }}"
      with_indexed_items: "{{ groups.some-hosts }}"
    - {role: ansible-zookeeper, zookeeper_hosts: "{{ zkh }}" }
```

I am assuming that your `set_fact` are working properly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this didn't work for me: `ERROR! no action detected in task`. Using `pre_task` worked instead.